# UITableViewAutomaticDimension NOT adjusting to UILabel text height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a messaging app and have set the labels constraints to 8 on each side of the bubble view. I have not set a height constraint and am trying to figure out why the label is randomly showing MORE height and the wrong size on some cells when scrolling:

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30
```

The labels are set to number of lines 0 and also word wrap.

```
    func configureCell(message: MessageCD) {

    self.message = message

    let username = message.getSender()?.username
    let text = message.text

    if username == UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: USERNAME) as? String {

        senderLbl.text = text
        recipientBubbleView.isHidden = true
        senderBubbleView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        recipientLbl.text = text
        senderBubbleView.isHidden = true
        recipientBubbleView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

I also tried using sizeToFit() right after the label is set but this also does not work. See attached image.[image]

Comment: Xcode 8 or Xcode 9?

Comment: Also what are the constraints on the bubbleview?

Comment: Xcode 8 and the constraints on the bubble view are pinned to sides 8 with a leading and trailing of >= 100 from the edge depending on if its on the left or right. The bubbleview has no height or anything else

Comment: are the top and bottom 8 as well?

Comment: Add self.layoutIfNeeded() on the cell after the if/else statement in configureCell and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I tried that and yes top and bottom 8 as well as the leading or trailing is 8. Then depending on the open side it is 100 >= from the edge

Comment: Last try since I am on a mobile but set compression resistant and content hugging on the label to a really high number and give that a go

Answer (score 1):

Content Hugging Priority Fixed the issue.

```
if msgUsername == UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: USERNAME) as? String {

        recipientLbl.setContentHuggingPriority(250, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical)
        senderLbl.setContentHuggingPriority(750, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical)
        senderLbl.text = message.text
        senderLbl.sizeToFit()
        recipientUsernameLbl.isHidden = true
        recipientBubbleView.isHidden = true
        senderBubbleView.isHidden = false

    } else {

        senderLbl.setContentHuggingPriority(250, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical)
        recipientLbl.setContentHuggingPriority(750, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical)
        recipientLbl.text = message.text
        recipientUsernameLbl.text = msgUsername
        recipientUsernameLbl.isHidden = false
        recipientLbl.sizeToFit()
        senderBubbleView.isHidden = true
        recipientBubbleView.isHidden = false
    }
```